# R Generate frequency table

Tags: r, vector, frequency

I have sample vector like this:

```
v <- c(1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 4)
```

What I'd like to get is frequency table which will tell me frequencies of numbers followed by another numbers .

Output:

```
  1 2 3 4
1 0 1 0 1
2 1 0 1 0
3 1 1 1 0
4 1 0 1 0
```

And then the same values in percentages.

Comment: What do you want to do if not all integers from 1 to max(v) are in your vector? For example, suppose there were no '2's in v. Do you want the output to exclude that row and column, or to include a row and column of zeroes? This will affect how you access the results. Of course it may be that your application always has at least 1 of each from 1 to max(v)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm thinking what you are meaning is correct, try:

```
xtabs(~v[-1]+v[1:(length(v)-1)])
     v[1:(length(v) - 1)]
v[-1] 1 2 3 4
    1 0 1 0 1
    2 1 0 1 0
    3 1 1 1 0
    4 1 0 1 0
```

This doesn't match with your expected output, but I'm not sure how you arrived at that.

For percentages, use `prop.table`:

```
prop.table(xtabs(~v[-1]+v[1:(length(v)-1)]))*100
     v[1:(length(v) - 1)]
v[-1]        1        2        3        4
    1  0.00000 11.11111  0.00000 11.11111
    2 11.11111  0.00000 11.11111  0.00000
    3 11.11111 11.11111 11.11111  0.00000
    4 11.11111  0.00000 11.11111  0.00000
```

Comment: v[-length(v)] should be a bit simpler than v[1:(length(v)-1)]

Comment: Thank you! I like this solution. But I have one more question. Shouldn't percentages in column sum up to 100% ? That is behavior that I expect.

Comment: You can use the `margin` argument to `prop.table` to specify row, column or total proportions, eg for column: `margin=2`

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way:

```
## Construct a data frame in which each row is a pair of consecutive characters.
df <- data.frame(a=head(v,-1), b=v[-1])
## tabulate frequencies of the ordered pairs
res <- xtabs(~a+b, df)
res
#    b
# a   1 2 3 4
#   1 0 1 1 1
#   2 1 0 1 0
#   3 0 1 1 1
#   4 1 0 0 0

res/sum(res)
#    b
# a           1         2         3         4
#   1 0.0000000 0.1111111 0.1111111 0.1111111
#   2 0.1111111 0.0000000 0.1111111 0.0000000
#   3 0.0000000 0.1111111 0.1111111 0.1111111
#   4 0.1111111 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Comment: I like the simple way of constructing pairs of consecutive values.

Comment: Well nice solution, but this table doesn't look like one in my example. For example, 3 is followed by 1 once but your result has zero in that cell.

Comment: Just switch the formula to `res <- xtabs(~b+a, df)` to get your posted results. (When I put this up, your results matrix still contained 2s and a 4, so I couldn't make out that you wanted rows/ columns in 'to/from' rather than the more usual 'from/to' arrangement.)